# What are all types of variable expansions supported by Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

I am currently using Memgraph as a graph databases in my learining project. I understand that variable expansions play a significant role in traversing graphs, especially when querying relationships between nodes.

Based on the capabilities of Memgraph, could someone specify the types of variable expansions that are supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memgraph supports following types of variable expansions:

1. **Depth-first search (DFS):** DFS is an algorithm that visits vertices in a graph as far as possible along each branch before backtracking.
2. **Breadth-first search (BFS):** BFS operates by visiting all the vertices of the current level before moving to vertices of the next level. BFS in Memgraph is implemented through shortest path algorithms:

   - **SingleSourceShortestPath:** Finds the shortest path from a single source node to all other nodes in the graph.
   - **STShortestPath:** Computes the shortest path between a specific source node and a specific target node.
3. **WeightedShortestPath:** This algorithm takes into account edge weights when calculating the shortest paths.
4. **AllShortestPath:** Finds all shortest paths between all pairs of nodes in a graph.